# Nested Nuxt + Tailwind (Please enable a CSS nesting plugin *before* Tailwind in your configuration)

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css

use Nuxt v2.15.8  + Tailwind. Have a warns about nesting in all files where using  after npm run dev and each refresh, example

> ```
>  WARN  in ./components/Cabinet/CabinetSidebar/CabinetSidebarMenu.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=postcss&
> ```
>
> friendly-errors 18:24:59
>
> ```
>     Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> ```
>
> friendly-errors 18:24:59
> Warning
>
> ```
>     (99:2) Nested CSS was detected, but CSS nesting has not been configured correctly.
>     Please enable a CSS nesting plugin *before* Tailwind in your configuration.
>     See how here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting
> ```

File nuxt.config.js

```
import 'reflect-metadata'
import { join } from 'path'
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
export default {

    head: {...},

    css: ['~assets/css/styles.css'],
    loading: false,

    components: {
        dirs: ['~/components', '~/components/Base'],
    },

    buildModules: [
        '@nuxt/typescript-build',
        'nuxt-typed-vuex',
        '@nuxtjs/router-extras',
        '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
        '@nuxtjs/composition-api/module',
    ],
    tailwindcss: {
        configPath: 'tailwind.config.js',
        cssPath: '~/assets/css/tailwind.css',
        // jit: true,
        exposeConfig: true,
        config: {},
    },
    modules: [
        // 'nuxt-ssr-cache',
        // 'nuxt-lazy-load',
        'vue-scrollto/nuxt',
        '@nuxtjs/axios',
        'nuxt-i18n',
        '@nuxtjs/svg',
        'cookie-universal-nuxt',
        '@nuxtjs/toast',
        '@nuxtjs/google-analytics'
    ],

    build: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: {
                'postcss-import': true,
                'postcss-nested': {},
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Didn't find information on this error, maybe someone can suggest a solution

Comment: solved by adding `'tailwindcss/nesting': {}` in build -> postcss -> plugins

Comment: Could you please add an answer and share your solution there for the use of others?

Comment: build: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: {
                'postcss-import': true,
                'tailwindcss/nesting': {}
                'postcss-nested': {},
            },
        },
    },

Comment: Shouldn't there also be the "normal" tailwindcss plugin like described here in the docs? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting . Also, when using postcss-nested instead of the postcss-nested, that is integrated in tailwind, you should use     require('tailwindcss/nesting')(require('postcss-nesting')), according to the docs. Despite that, it is not working for me. I have to say, I'm not using @nuxt/tailwindcss but have integrated it myself.

Answer (score 5):

As Dmitry himself mentioned in the comments, to fix this problem, 'tailwindcss/nesting': {}  should be added to postcss plugins in the build section of 'nuxt.config' file, so it would be like this:

```js
build: {
    postcss: {
        plugins: {
            'postcss-import': true,
            'tailwindcss/nesting': {}, 
             'postcss-nested': {},
        },
    },
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this type of problem and I fixed it by adding this code:

I added these lines on `nuxt.config.ts`:

```
plugins: {
'postcss-import': {},
'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
tailwindcss: {},
autoprefixer: {},
}
```

**In short, it is better to have a code similar to the following code** in `nuxt.config.ts`:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
ssr: false,
alias: {
    'class-validator': 'class-validator/cjs/index.js',
},
postcss: {
    plugins: {
        'postcss-import': {},
        'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    },
},
css: [
    '~/assets/css/main.css',
],
modules: [
    "@nuxt/content",
],
content: {
    // https://content.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration
},
components: {
    global: true,
    dirs: ["~/components"],
},
runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
        VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE,
        VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE,
        VUE_APP_BASE_ROUTE: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_ROUTE,
        VUE_APP_NAME: process.env.VUE_APP_NAME,
        VUE_APP_Host: process.env.VUE_APP_Host,
        VUE_WSS_Host: process.env.VUE_WSS_Host,
    },
},
```

});